# Webcam Security Software Running on Computer - Any OS?

Tags: security, webcam, cctv

Are there any security room-monitoring software that runs through a webcam on the computer? (This thread isn't a duplicate of [Free CCTV software using webcam running on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/56641/free-cctv-software-using-webcam-running-on-windows))

The features I'm looking for:

-Records and monitors any movement within the room through webcam

-When movement is detected, there are specific markings within the video so you could easily skip through the footage to the point where the movement has been detected/email alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Vitamin D Video](http://www.vitamindinc.com/).

Answer (score 1):

This post on [lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/) might be informative: [Use your webcam as a security camera](http://lifehacker.com/203905/use-your-webcam-as-a-security-camera)

There is also this commercial app:

> [Watcher](http://download.cnet.com/Watcher/3000-2348_4-10056610.html) does motion detection, e-mail/phone alert, video/audio logging, broadcasting and more. Used together with RemoteView

Comment: Yes, I have seen that before too, but I'm looking for something that does more.

Comment: @JFW - You should edit your question to include apps you have tried and rejected (and perhaps explain what was lacking).